# Retry Database connection Dropwizard

Tags: java, jdbc, dropwizard, jdbi

How do I retry to connect to my database if the connection does not work for the first time?
I am using jdbi3 for my database connection

```java
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    startApp(args);
  }

  private static void startApp(String[] args) throws Exception {
    try {
      new Application().run(args);
    } catch(SQLException ex) {
      System.out.println("Could not connect to database.");
      System.out.println("Try reconnecting...");
      TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);
      startApp(args);
    }
  }
```

I implemented this since `new Application().run(args)` is throwing the `SQLException` if there was no connection but the exception never got caught.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Automatic retry of transactions/requests in Dropwizard/JPA/Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39949017/automatic-retry-of-transactions-requests-in-dropwizard-jpa-hibernate)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This will eventually cause a stack overflow. Better:

```
while (true) {
    try (
        new Application().run(args);
        return;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        continue;
    }
}
```

But that's not all: This will retry on *any* SQL exception. So, if, say, the db is up but the first thing the app does is, say, create a table, but that table already exists, this will just end up re-trying and failing, forever, at a 2 second interval, and that's quite yucky. I suggest checking which -actual- SQLException is thrown if the DB is down (presumably, that's why you want to retry: Wait for the DB to return) and catching *ONLY* that one. Note ethat SQLException has more methods than most exception types do, such as .getSQLState(), which you should check to figure out if the error is in fact 'cannot connect to DB engine', vs some other problem.

Furthermore, it is likely that Application's run() method is catching *all* exceptions, and will log them, which means your attempt to catch them isn't going to do anything. In this case, you'd have to edit the code of run().

Comment: Is there no other way than editing the code of run()? Your solution will also not work since the exceptions will also not be caught. However, I would really like to avoid to edit the run() since I am working on an open-source project and I do not want to ship alternative library code

Comment: If the run() method catches that exception (and that does seem like that's happening), there is no easy alternative. You could try to live-patch that code but that is extremely complicated.